# why am i not able to pause,resume or quit music in python file?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, audio-player, mixer

```
import pygame
from pygame import mixer

pygame.init()
mixer.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((300,200))
mixer.music.load("a.mp3")
mixer.music.play()
print("press 'p' to pause and 'r' to resume")
print(("press'q' to quit"))
running=True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            running=False
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_p:
                mixer.music.pause()
            if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                mixer.music.unpause()
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                running=False
pygame.QUIT
exit()
```

1.i have imported mixer from pygame.All works fine,music plays,but i cannot pause or resume or exit the music on commands.

Comment: you might tried to enter the input in run console,instead try clicking on the pygame window and press there,your problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

I have run this code successfully with the aforementioned functionality you deemed is not working. All keystrokes are being registered properly and causing pause, resume, and quit to execute. Make sure your focus is inside of the pygame window when issuing these keyboard commands.

Just to note I did use a wav file instead of mp3 but shouldn't make a difference in this instance.